# iOS Settings bundle, read and write?

Tags: objective-c

i have a settings bundle file with a slider and a text field. How can i, in code, get the value from the slider and display it using the text field? Thank you!

Comment: `IOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS) is not the same as `iOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) please make sure you use the correct heading as this can create confusion in what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

As states in [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) you can read the value by it key from the [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSInteger settingsValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:<SettingsBundleKey>];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you possibly give a more straightforward answer to my situation please?

Comment: @DanVasile How is providing the code for you not a straight answer? This is probably the simplest and most straight to the point answer +1. All you need to do is replace `<SettingsBundleKey>` with your key in your settings bundle.

Comment: @Popeye when i read the initial message, there wasn't any code so that is why i wrote, sorry for the inconvenience....well thank you, that clears stuff up...but how do you change the text of a textfield in the settings bundle programatically?

Comment: @DanVasile You can set the value, like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"My new text" forKey:@"< SettingsBundleKey>"]`.

Comment: @DanVasile I'm sorry for that then.